# Unable to Convert Date and Time to LocalDateTime [Java]

Tags: java, date, datetime, pattern-matching, localdate

I'm trying to convert the string `Wed July 2019 10:53 PM` to `LocalDateTime` object using the following code:

```
String dateAndTimeAsStr = "Wed July 2019 10:53 PM";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMMM yyyy h:mm a");
LocalDateTime dateAndTimeAsLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTimeAsStr, formatter);
```

Yet when I run this code I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed July 2019 10:53 PM' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfWeek=3, MonthOfYear=7, Year=2019},ISO resolved to 22:53 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Changing `yyyy` to `YYYY` and `h` to `hh` did not yield any different results.

According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767) and [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) it seems my pattern matches the text supplied.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks

Comment: Which `LocalDateTime` had you expected as result of the parsing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Missing day-of-month

Your input string lacks the day of month. It says "July 2019" but not what *day* within July.

The formatted date string is irreversible (as in you can format existing LocalDateTime using the formatter, but cannot parse it back). as it's missing the day value.

Comment: I tried it on my end and it worked for me. Or you can use the "Date" object as suggested in answer below which is more forgiving.